# Is there a way to rerun a pasted block of code in spark shell?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-shell

I regularly copy blocks of code into spark-shell and run the block using

`:paste`
`ctrl-d`

Sometimes it errors because another line of code is required first e.g. an import. Once I have added any other requirements in, I would like to rerun the whole pasted block. Is there a shortcut for doing this, rather than re-copying it, re-pasting? Something like reverse search but for whole blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put together all the blocks in a file and run

> scala> :load [path of file]